# Table Join in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am working in rails 2, I have one table users and other table lms_users. In lms_users table, id from users table is coming as foreign key. I want to join two tables in such a way, so i get only those users, whose entry is not in lms_users.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User
  named_scope :not_in_lms_users, {
    :conditions => [ "users.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM lms_users)" ]
  }
end
```

or

```
class User
  named_scope :not_in_lms_users, {
    :conditions => "lms_users.user_id IS NULL",
    :joins => "LEFT OUTER JOIN lms_users ON lms_users.user_id = users.id"
  }
end
```

Just check, but I think the second one is more efficient. This should work :

```
User.not_in_lms_users
```